# "Array" type parameter caused error " Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string"

Tags: php, laravel

I am passing an Array as parameter in a function, however, it caused this error. I saw an Array parameter "$datas=array($code,$data['minute'])" was passed in as 'Array'.  "SMSController->sendTemplateSMS('12313232', Array, '1')"

Here is the process:

1. Assigned an array to the variable: $datas=array($code,$data['minute']);
2. Passed this variable to the function: $this->sendTemplateSMS($data['userMobile'],$datas,"1");
3. From the log, it was passed in as a class "Array", and caused the error: 1 \app\Http\Controllers\SMSController.php(100): App\Http\Controllers\SMSController->sendTemplateSMS('12313232', Array, '1')

I don't know what's wrong. Anyone can help?

Code to invoke the function:

```
  function sendVerifyCode(){
     $code=rand(100000,999999);
     $data['userMobile'] = $_POST['usermobile'];
     $data['userKey'] = $code;
     $data['created_at'] = carbon::now();
     $data['updated_at'] = carbon::now();
     $data['minute']=1;
     $datas=array($code,$data['minute']);
     $if_send=$this->sendTemplateSMS($data['userMobile'],$datas,"1");
     ....

   function sendTemplateSMS($to,$datas,$tempId)
{
    //init REST SDK
    $accountSid=$this->smsConfig['accountSid'];
    $accountToken=$this->smsConfig['accountToken'];
    $appId=$this->smsConfig['appId'];
    $serverIP=$this->smsConfig['serverIP'];
    $serverPort=$this->smsConfig['serverPort'];
    $softVersion=$this->smsConfig['softVersion'];
    $rest = new SMS\REST($serverIP,$serverPort,$softVersion);
    $rest->setAccount($accountSid,$accountToken);
    $rest->setAppId($appId);
    $phone=$to;
    $codes=$datas;
    $template=$tempId;

    // send SMS
    echo "Sending TemplateSMS to $phone <br/>";
    $result = $rest->sendTemplateSMS($phone,$codes,$template);
```

Error:
[2016-06-11 15:51:30] localhost.ERROR: ErrorException: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in 
\app\Http\Controllers\SMSController.php:65

Stack trace:

0 \app\Http\Controllers\SMSController.php(65): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(4096, 'Object of class...', 'app\...', 65, Array)

1 \app\Http\Controllers\SMSController.php(100): App\Http\Controllers\SMSController->sendTemplateSMS('12313232', Array, '1')

2 [internal function]: App\Http\Controllers\SMSController->sendVerifyCode()

Comment: It's probably trying to return an object rather than a string, check on line 65 & `var_dump` / `dd()` whatever is there to give you a better understanding.

Comment: not enough code provided for debugging.. as the error is general error that occurs when you try to treat class/instance as a string :)

Comment: @jakehallas Here is the process:  

1. I assigned the value to an array: $datas=array($code,$data['minute']);

2. I passed this variable as parameter to the function:  $this->sendTemplateSMS($data['userMobile'],$datas,"1");

3. However, it is treated as a Class "Array" passed in: 1 \app\Http\Controllers\SMSController.php(100): App\Http\Controllers\SMSController->sendTemplateSMS('12313232', Array, '1')

Comment: Sidenote: data is the plural of datum - the singular form of data.

Comment: @RyanVincent please see the question, I've added.